# Phone Number Validator Button will not work

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys i've been having some issues with calling my javascript function to my main HTML page.

I've got the javascript code:

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
  {  
      return true;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
     alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
     return false;  
  }  
}
```

But when i call it in my HTML i have this code:

```
<input type='text' name='text1'/>Phone Number: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="phonenumber(document.form1.text1)"/>
```

Are you able to assist me with this? sorry i'm kinda new to this :(

Thanks!

Comment: why not you used onkeypress

Answer (score 3):

Your `onclick` attribute needs to know if the validation passed or not. In other words, you should **return** the value from your validator function.

```
... onclick="return phonenumber(document.form1.text1)" ...
```

Comment: I've got this so far:

<input type='text' name='text1'/>Phone Number: <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return phonenumber(document.form1.text1)"> 
will this be right? 

Also will i need to close the tag?

Comment: when i tried to call the function it just redirects me back to the same page which is weird

Comment: To what URL do you submit your form to?

Comment: Do you mean the file path? its an offline one but its in my directory

Comment: @user1618490 - No you do not need to close the input tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you using `onlclick` method for validate phone no. field. I have a function try this for validation of number

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) ) // put your condition here
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

and fire it by using

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class=""  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"   />
```